# Mocking environment with Slim3 for CLI

Tags: slim, slim-3

I am trying to mock an environment to enable slim3 cli interface.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
array_shift($argv);
$pathInfo = implode('/', $argv);

if (empty($pathinfo)) {
  $pathinfo = '--help';
}
$config = ['environment'=>\Slim\Http\Environment::mock(['REQUEST_URI' => $pathInfo])];
$app = new \Slim\App($config);

$app->get('test:output',function(){
  exit("Arrived!");
});

$app->run();
```

However when I run the code `php bin/run test:example` absolutely nothing happens.

If I trap the request and get the request URI it's returned as "/".

Has anyone else had this problem and got round it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems that REQUEST_URI doesn't work without starting `/`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935589/slim-3-console-execution-for-cron) for details.

Also take a look at [Cilex](https://github.com/Cilex/Cilex) — a special framework for CLI commands, not HTTP routes.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making my own in the end!